How do i run Azure C# Http Trigger Function locally in https with debugging?
I have setup certificates et cetera, and I use this command to start my Functions:
func start --cert C:/temp/localhost.pfx --password password

This works but it doesn't have debugging. I am already using VS Code and have can run locally with debugging, or I can run locally with HTTPS, but I can't find a way to do both of them together.
Is there a way to use Azure HTTP triggered Functions with HTTPS and debugging locally in vs code?
UPDATE: you can't do it
https://damienbod.com/2019/03/14/running-local-azure-functions-in-visual-studio-with-https/
https://cmatskas.com/using-https-with-azure-functions-in-local-development/
You can set up to use https but as soon as you add --useHttps debugging doesn't work.
Also at the time of posting this you also have to remove the bin and obj folders at before running it or it says there are two proj files.
{
      "label":"runSecureHost",
      "type":"func",
      "command":"func start --cert C:/temp/localhost.pfx --password yourP@ssword --useHttps --debug",
      "isBackground":true,
      "presentation":{
        "reveal":"always"
      },
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
      }
    }


To run the Azure function locally with https and in debugging, use below command-
func start --useHttps --cors * --cert "certificate path" --password "password" --debug


I have created an azure Http triggered function and able to run it in https with debugging.

C:\Users\****\functionApp\78702373>func start --useHttps --cors * --cert "******\functionApp\78702373\localhost.pfx" --password "password" --debug
> dotnet build --output bin\output 
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\Users\****\functionApp\78702373\78702373.csproj (in 461 ms).
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\Users\****\functionApp\78702373\obj\Debug\net8.0\WorkerExtensions\WorkerExtensions.csproj (in 414 ms).
  WorkerExtensions -> C:\Users\****\functionApp\78702373\obj\Debug\net8.0\WorkerExtensions\buildout\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.dll
  78702373 -> C:\Users\****\functionApp\78702373\bin\output\78702373.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:04.33



Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5801 Commit hash: N/A +5ac2f09758b98257e728dd1b5576ce5ea9ef68ff (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.34.1.22669

[2024-07-04T06:52:28.400Z] Found C:\Users\****\functionApp\78702373\78702373.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2024-07-04T06:52:31.305Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        HttpTrigger1: [GET,POST] https://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-07-04T06:52:36.261Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000BF6D1ED5'.
[2024-07-04T06:52:55.901Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=be8e6e8a-f36d-45d7-b460-67c3f491a03d)
[2024-07-04T06:52:56.116Z] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-07-04T06:52:56.125Z] Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
[2024-07-04T06:52:56.197Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=be8e6e8a-f36d-45d7-b460-67c3f491a03d, Duration=317ms) 



thanks but the debugger doesn't seem to attach, in vs code when i run from the debugger menu the debugger control panel comes up, so i can move through the code as its run, but this doesn't seem to happen with this?

@EnenDaveyBoy Yes, you will not get it using this command but you will get all the debugging related logs in terminal

thanks i am not bother if its command line or not, the only example i found to run https was using command line with the command in the op, is there a way to run the debugger and have the function run in https?

You want the debugger to be attached while debugging? I believe we can only get the debugging logs as we need to use the command line because of the need of providing details in regards to https (--useHttps) and certificate ( --cert )

i found it, thanks for the help https://cmatskas.com/using-https-with-azure-functions-in-local-development/

I believe the link you have shared also given the same command which I have added in my answer. I don't see any difference in that link

the first link i used to create a cert and reference it the second link shows you need to add it to the vs code task.json file, i couldn't get any debugging to work adding --debug, it ran fine but break points didn't pause the code etc. Thanks for the help though

changed my mind you can't do it as soon as you add --useHttps debugging doesn't work, it runs without problem but debugging doesn't

Yes, this is what I mentioned in my earlier comment that as we need to use --useHttps, so it might not be feasible to attach the debugger

thanks i have reported it as a bug on github
